# Handlers Swallow Exceptions

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Consider the following handler:

```
public class CreateProjectHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        // it does not matter what kind of exception this is:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This is a test!");
    }

}
```

From a customer and developer perspective it's pretty clear what should happen when this handler is executed: an error message of some kind should pop up.

What happens is: Nothing.

More accurate: the exception is logged into the error log (and console, if started from Eclipse). But the user sees nothing, in fact he doesn't even know there was an error.

I could fix this by catching `Exception` for each and every handler, but besides being ugly and cumbersome it contradicts each style guide ever.

Is there a better way to handle the exceptions swallowed by handlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Eclipse 4 (e4 or 3.x compatbility mode) add a class implementing `IEventLoopAdvisor` to the application context. The `eventLoopException` method will be called for the unhandled exceptions.

A suitable place to set this up for e4 is the `@PostContextCreate` of the RCP life cycle class:

```java
@PostContextCreate
public void postContextCreate(IEclipseContext context)
{
  // Event loop advisor for error handling

  context.set(IEventLoopAdvisor.class, new EventLoopAdvisor());
```

You must also implement `eventLoopIdle`, it is very important that this calls `display.sleep()`. A standard method would be:

```java
@Override
public void eventLoopIdle(final Display display)
{
  display.sleep();
}
```

For 3.x compatibility mode there is a default event loop advisor installed after the post context create which delegates to the workbench `WorkbenchAdvisor`. If you are using your own advisor in the RCP you can override the `eventLoopException` method of the advisor.

Comment: I tried using [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4LifeCycle/article.html) to add the `LifeCycleManager`. The `@PostContextCreate` gets called, but neither method of the `IEventLoopAdvisor` is called. Do you have any idea, why?

Comment: It looks like 3.x compatibilty mode installs its own event loop advisor later during the startup delegating to `WorkbenchAdvisor` - see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way that works for my E3 compatibility application: overridding `WorkbenchAdvisor#eventLoopException(Throwable)`:

```
public class ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor extends WorkbenchAdvisor {

    @Override
    public void eventLoopException(Throwable exception) {
        // do magic here
    }

    // [snipped other methods]
}
```