# How to prevent error dialogs from appearing?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

When an exception occurs (such as null pointer exception or SWT exception) they produce an 'Internal Error' ErrorDialog. I want to stop these popups from appearing (but keep other dialogs) as the errors will be logged instead.

I have tried setting the IApplicationContext.EXIT_DATA_PROPERTY and using the --launcher.suppressErrors (Executable) program argument. Both didn't seem to work...

Vogella have a tutorial which shows how to use/create the dialog here: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDialogs/article.html#errordialog

I'm expecting the dialog to not appear when an exception is thrown.

Comment: Is this an e4 RCP (using an Application.e4xmi ...) or a 3.x compatbility mode RCP?

Comment: @greg-449 this is using an Application.e4xmi

Comment: You probably with an IEventLoopAdvisor see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47159115/2670892)

Comment: yes this solved it thanks